# Adding is_visible rather than destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rather than a guideline being deleted, I'd like it to be marked as not visible (so it's still in my database but users won't see it listed). This is having a few major issues

1. I don't seem to be able to delete guidelines from the view
2. When I try to view my admin side - guidelines I get the error

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment_ids_contains'
>   for #):

I suspect no 2 is unrelated but didn't cause me a problem before I made the changes below.
In my guidelines.rb model I added

```
default_scope where(:visible => true)
attr_accessible :visible
```

in guideline_controller.rb I changed the destroy and create actions to

```
def destroy
    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
    @guideline.visible=false
    #@guideline.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to guidelines_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


def create
    @guideline = current_user.guidelines.new(params[:guideline])
    @guideline.visible=true

    respond_to do |format|

      if @guideline.save
        format.html { redirect_to @guideline, notice: 'Guideline was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @guideline, status: :created, location: @guideline } 
      else
        @specialties = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @guideline.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in admin/guidelines.rb I added

```
   column :visible
```

and I added a db migration

```
class AddVisibleColumnToGuidelines < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :guidelines, :visible, :boolean   
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't see `comment_ids_contains` in your code snippets. Can you relevant code and where you are getting error. also tell where you are calling destroy???

Comment: actually I can't find it in my code either - is that possible or must it be there somewhere?

Comment: Show us part of the view, there should be a hint as to the error.

Comment: this is something to do with activeadmin Showing /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `comment_ids_contains' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Guideline:0x007f9ec4553448>

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your activeadmin configuration or with relations defined in one of your models. I'd need more context to debug the problem.

Comment: yes, you are right.  this is obviously a separate problem to the 'visible' issue.  I will post this as a separate question as I am confusing the issue by asking about two things at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, doing:

```
@guideline.visible=false
```

is not enough as you're only changing the Ruby object. You have to call `save!` to propagate changes back to the DB:

```
@guideline.visible = false
@guideline.save!
```

You can also use `update_attribute` to do it in one step:

```
@guideline.update_attribute(:visible, false)
```

although this method skips some steps (like validations), so better [read about it](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) first.

Another thing is that you should probably use the following code to find a guideline, unless you want other users to delete each other's guidelines:

```
current_user.guidelines.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Yes, I think you have solved the problem #1 thank you (I do want users to be able to delete each other's guidelines - it's sort of a wiki).  The issue now is no 2 - I can't get into my activeadmin guidelines to see if it's still showing in the database or not...

Answer (score 2):

I can see your question has already been answered by Michal but it seems like your code could be tidier.  Having to set visible to true on create is extra effort that shouldn't be needed.

Instead of "visible", I would add a datetime field to your table called "deleted_at".  Then in your destroy method, you can just do:

```
@guideline.deleted_at = Time.zone.now
@guideline.save!
```

This also has the benefit of storing the date/time when it was deleted in case that's useful later.

Your default scope can then be:

```
 default_scope where(deleted_at: nil)
```

Comment: @skirkpatrick Yeah I wasn't sure if appropriate to post but am hopeful the OP sees it, might be a useful pattern for them.

Comment: OP had seen it!  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, you should set the default value to true by adding default: true at the end of your add_column method call. You will also have to set all existing guidelines :visible to true so that they are visible. If you use a default, you won't have to explicitly set visible in your create method.

If you want to set visible to true without a default db value, it's better to do it in a before_create callback in your guideline model than to set it in the controller.